# Can data be recovered from a "broken SSD" in a similar manner as from an HDD?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd

Can data be recovered from a "broken SSD" in a similar manner as from an HDD? Or once the drive is "broken" is the data "toast"?

EDIT: I don't mean using the same methods. I am just trying to find out if data is generally recoverable or not.

Comment: Yes, no, maybe. It depends on the nature of the failure and what you mean by "in a similar manner as from an HDD".

Comment: I don't mean using the same methods. I am just trying to find out if data is generally recoverable or not.

Comment: @Xavierjazz - You need to narrow down the question.  It depends on HOW it fails.  Data recovery is possible on SSD devices if that's what your asking.  **File recovery software will work with SSDs.**

Comment: @Ramhound: Yours is the answer to my question when I asked it, but the responses have given me a much clearer understanding. Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 4):

NAND chips are typically standardized parts with datasheets available.  All the ones I've seen on flash drives are BGA mounted, which is difficult to remove and work with, but not impossible.  So it's not impossible for someone to pull chips off the board and read them in another device.

Getting meaningful data off of them (i.e. what was written by an operating system) without intimate knowledge of how the controller is distributing data to them exactly is extremely difficult.  However, it is likely the developer of the controller has utilities available for this or similar purposes, or could perform such an operation if desired.  It's also possible some SSD boards have UART pins or pads where you can talk to the controller over the serial port and perform low-level operations, such as raw dumping of the flash chips.  I don't know this for sure, though.  You could on this [SSD development kit](http://www.openssd-project.org/wiki/Jasmine_OpenSSD_Platform) I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Unlike an HDD, an SSD has no separate electronics board that controls/reads/writes to platters inside the capsule -- which is one of the biggest tricks to recovering data from a physically damaged or electronically "fried" HDD: you can plug in a good controller board and the data inside the capsule is usually (mostly) okay.  With an SSD, it's all electronics, and there isn't any practical way to replace the microcontroller that levels wear and handles reads and writes (surface mount chips as opposed to a complete board with connectors and cables).  On a national security level, it might well be possible to disassemble the device and individually read out the data from the flash RAM chips -- but on a practical basis, if an SSD won't detect on multiple computers, or won't read back data, or won't hold a format (indicative that it won't write), it's done and everything on it is gone.

Yet another good reason to have good backup habits for your SSD (though most modern SSDs will outlast the user, barring electircal surges, static damage, or physical destruction).

Comment: " (though most modern SSDs will outlast the user, barring electircal surges, static damage, or physical destruction)." Is this actually true? You are implying that an SSD will live for decades. I can find no research to back this up. Please post any references you have.

Comment: I'm not at home, so don't have the model number of the one I bought recently, but it had documentation with it that suggested a working life of 8 years at 10 GB/day write rate, or 80 years at a more ordinary 1 GB/day -- and this was a budget unit, the first I ever saw at around $70 for 250 GB capacity.

Answer (score 1):

In general SSD recovery is nowhere near as successful as HDD recovery. The SSD devices are much less resilient, and are frequently proprietary in design as opposed to the much more consistent HDD architecture. Then, too, the [TRIM function makes recovery much less likely](http://techgage.com/article/too_trim_when_ssd_data_recovery_is_impossible/) and [SMART is not a good predictor of failure](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/archive/disk_failures.pdf).

If the filesystem is detected when you attach the SSD to a controller, you have a reasonably good chance of recovering at least some data. The best luck I have had is with [PHOTOREC](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec) which is a free download, and free to use.